# Custom View Xib for MKAnnotationView button tap

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkannotationview

I'm making a custom MKAnnotationView and i have a button inside the xib, inwhich i want to get when is touchedup inside.

Although there are questions with the same issue, none of them is working with my code.
I have the following.

```
class CustomCalloutView: MKAnnotationView {

     var didTapGoButton: (() -> Void)?

    // MARK: - Detect taps on callout

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let rect = self.bounds;
        var isInside: Bool = rect.contains(point);
        if(!isInside)
        {
            for view in self.subviews
            {
                isInside = view.frame.contains(point);
                if isInside
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isInside;
    }
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if (hitView != nil)
        {
            self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
        }
        return hitView
    }

    @IBAction func viewEventDetails(_ sender: Any) {
        didTapGoButton?()
    }

 func configureCell(events: Events) {

  eventName.text = events.eventName

 }
}
```

ViewController

```
class EventAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
    var myEvent:Events?
}


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        guard let annotation = view.annotation else { return }
        if view.annotation!.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self){
            return
        }
         if let eventAnnotation = view.annotation as? EventAnnotation {
                    let theEvent = eventAnnotation.myEvent
                    let customView = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: self, options: nil))?[0] as! CustomCalloutView;
                    let calloutViewFrame = customView.frame;
                    customView.frame = CGRect(x: -calloutViewFrame.size.width/2.23, y: -calloutViewFrame.size.height-7, width: 315, height: 298)
                    customView.configureCell(events: theEvent!)
                    customView.didTapGoButton = { [weak mapView ] in
                        print(theEvent?.eventName ?? "noname")
                    }
                    view.addSubview(customView)

                }
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView)
    {
        for childView:AnyObject in view.subviews{
            childView.removeFromSuperview();
        }
    }
```

So when i tap the button nothing is being printed !

Any idea where is my mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , the idea is to position the customView with in the boundary of the pinAnnotationView image as any click out side of it will be considered a didSelect method call , so play with frame until click detected , it will work either in custom view or viewController

```
    customView.frame = CGRect(x: -calloutViewFrame.size.width/2.23, y: calloutViewFrame.size.height, width: 315, height: 298)
```

and here is a demo to illustrate the situation

[customPinAnnotationButton](https://github.com/ShKhan9/customPinAnnotationButton)

Comment: in the view controller?

Comment: I cant get the instance of the `Events` in this way.

Comment: then add it in the custom view

Comment: both ways dont execute the function pressed.

Comment: don't expect this.  customView.didTapGoButton = { [weak mapView ] in
                        print(theEvent?.eventName ?? "noname")
                    }.       to run when you click the button it's on the fly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162743/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-sh-khan).